# Alternative to "A Pomodoro Timer for GNOME" for KDE

Tags: software-recommendation, webapps

Does anybody know one similar app like "[A Pomodoro Timer for GNOME](http://gnomepomodoro.org/)" which works with KDE? I use KDE and this one isn't compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [RSIBreak](https://userbase.kde.org/RSIBreak) may help. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install rsibreak`.

Also exists [Tomatoid](https://store.kde.org/content/show.php/Tomatoid?content=152459), but it is not packaged.

Answer (score 2):

Also try [Fokus](https://store.kde.org/p/1308861/) - Simple pomodoro timer plasmoid.